# Suggestion on reading resources on superconducting quantum computing

Tags: resource-request, superconducting-quantum-computing, experimental-realization, circuit-qed

I am a physics student who works with NMR spin-based quantum computing, now branching into superconductor-based qubits. So I am reading lecture notes by [Nathan K Langford](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.1897) and [Steve Girvin](http://www.capri-school.eu/lectureres/master_cqed_les_houches.pdf). I can understand the sections on quantum mechanics, condensed matter physics, and quantum computation. But I am facing issues with the sections in Steve Girvin talking about experiential implementation using transmission lines, coplanar waveguides, electronic circuitry, etc., because of my lack of expertise in electronic engineering. Hence, I request reading resources containing information regarding the superconducting qubit's electronic engineering aspect that would enhance my understanding of the lecture notes. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

[A Quantum Engineer’s Guide to Superconducting Qubits](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.06560) gives a nice overview of many aspects of current SC research. The bibliography is a good place to find more detailed info about specific topics.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will surely check it out